# Permission request alert for location services is not shown in watchOS 2

Tags: ios, watchkit, core-location, cllocationmanager, watchos-2

I'm following this simple [tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/A_watchOS_2_WatchKit_Map_Tutorial) to show the current location of the user on his watch, but for some reason, I am stuck in the 'Configuring the Containing iOS App' section because the message that is supposed to be displayed for requestion the permission is not shown. I don't know what can I be missing, could somebody help me?